# What the best way to move IBM Message Broker components between DEV, QA and PROD environments?

Tags: esb, ibm-mq, messagebroker

On a SOA project we start to employ IBM WebSphere Message Broker to orchestrate .NET-based web services. We have distinct DEV, QA and PROD environments for the system being developed.

WebSphere Message Broker Toolkit would be used to develop message flows in DEV. And with DEV everything is more or less clear.

For QA and PROD we aim to have repeatable and as automated and possible deployment procedure. With .NET portion it almost a no-brainer, but deployment to Message Broker seem to require substantial manual effort, which is not good.

What are recommendations for deployment to WebSphere Message Broker? What is the best way to package Message Broker components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You components (flows and so forth) will be packaged up as Broker Archive (.bar) files. You can use Ant to script the deployment of these components between environments, for example.

Comment: Hi Andy, do you know if the infrastructure components, i.e Nodes, queue managers, queues etc. can be created into some kind of deployable? I am trying to automate but seems we have no choice but to SSH from jenkins to target machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use scripts.

As Andy Piper says Ant works quite well.

Also be aware that you can use the CMP API which has been rebadged as the Message Broker API its quite comprehensive and lets you get at and modify information in you Broker Archive(BAR) files to a much more significant extent that just the various Broker commands you can invoke from a script.